# Popup when mouse hovers over button in excel 2010

Tags: excel, popup, mouseover

I have many buttons on a worksheet ( can't remember if they are activeX or not). I'd like to add a few lines describing what each button does when the cursor is hovering over the button. Is this even possible?
[image]